# how to merge code from subversion into TFS 2012 and back?

Tags: svn

how to merge code from subversion into TFS 2012 and back?
I was reading about SVNBridge to merge from svn to TFS. Is it possible to merge back from TFS to svn? what can I use for this?

Answer (score 0):

SVNBridge represents TFS repository as Subversion repo (transparently).

Thus - any operation, which you can perform with Subversion, you can (over bridge) perform with TFS